# About semaphore class

Tags: java, semaphore, doc

> Note that FIFO ordering necessarily applies to specific internal
>   points of execution within these methods.

from [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html)

What do they mean with internal points of execution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation immediately says after that:

> So, it is possible for one thread to invoke acquire before another, but reach the ordering point after the other

Which means this scenario is possible:

```
thread 1                 thread 2
--------                 --------
calls acquire()
                         calls acquire()
                         acquire() does its job
acquire() does its job
```

(where `acquires() does its job` is what the doc refers to as the "ordering point")

In short: there is no guarantee that, timely speaking, the first thread calling `acquire()` gets to acquire the semaphore first. What *is* guaranteed is that when it returns from `acquire()`, other `acquire()` callers will have to wait.

This is a rare occurrence, but possible.

Comment: why thread1 does not go ahead? and gives way to thread 2 to proceed?

Comment: @Rollerball the ordering point may not be the first statement in `acquire()`, and in the meanwhile the OS may have scheduled the thread away. It depends on the implementation of `.acquire()`. Some JVM implementations _may_ guarantee full FIFO (where "I" here would mean first scheduled), but the Javadoc explicitly says that this is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 1):

They are refereing to points of execution internal to the acquire() method. They mean that, in the implementation of acquire(), there is some 'ordering point' where the first thread to get there will be the first to leave. So, if thread A gets calls enters acquire() before B, but B gets to the ordering point first, B will come out first (despite entering acquire second).